# EF entities Deep Copy & Web Caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC3 framework together with EntityFramework 6 in a web app. I am storing most user specific data loaded with ef in server cache using system web caching. My DbContext is request specific(one instance per request). The problem is I also cache an ef entity object in cache which is user specific(separate cache key per user app). For each request i get it from cache and attach it to the current EF context using context.Attach. My problem is that if the same user logs in twice or multiple times(different browsers etc) at the same time the Entity that is cached is attached to multiple contexts, because the cache is global per server and the same object reference is retrieved.

I am getting an exception that the same entity is referenced multiple times by different contexts. I have tried to copy the entity when i get it from the cache but it has many foreign keys with children entities in it and this wouldn't be an option.

Does anyone has any idea what would be the solution in my case? I am trying to avoid getting the entity from database for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Point 5 of this [article](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0907071) describes the error you are getting. In a nutshell, EF6 puts a proxy wrapper around your entity with a reference to the original context it was attached to.

Prior to caching the entity, you must detach it from the DbContext.

You can look into using [EFCache](http://efcache.codeplex.com/) and setting up a policy that targets the entities you want to cache.